# 3706 Syntax error: expected something between an integer and ')'

Tags: sql, database, group-by, subquery, teradata

I'm struggling with finding out what the problem is, part of my code looks like this

```
(sel no_2, sum(L) from (
                sel no_2, colB, count(distinct(colC))
                from dbA.tblP as p
                    join dbB.tblI as i on p.id = i.id and p.no = i.no
                    join dbB.tblT as t on i.no_2 = t.no_2
                    join dbA.mp_tblA as a on t.no_2 = a.no_2) l 
                    ) as l
group by 1) as l
```

Teradata points at line with group by 1) in it. What should I put between '1' and ")" parentheses? Is there any way to work it out?

Comment: You should provide the whole query. It's hard to say anything with that tiny part.

Comment: okay, just tell me please how can i format it to code in comment?

Comment: Use "edit" button under the question and add the code there.

Comment: yeah i edited it, hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: Seems there's an extra bracket(along with the alias) in this part of code: `a.no_2) l`

Comment: `distinct` is not a function. Do `count(distinct colC)` to make code clearer.

Comment: Do not re-use the table aliases (`l`). It will confuse anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra `) l` in there that's causing the syntax error.  Try this:

```sql
SELECT no_2, SUM(L) 
FROM (
  SELECT no_2, colB, COUNT(DISTINCT colC) AS no_colC
  FROM dbA.tblP AS p
  INNER JOIN dbB.tblI AS i ON p.id = i.id AND p.no = i.no
  INNER JOIN dbB.tblT AS t ON i.no_2 = t.no_2
  INNER JOIN dbA.mp_tblA AS a ON t.no_2 = a.no_2
) AS l
GROUP BY 1
```

A few suggestions for readability, in addition to the comments:

- use `SELECT` instead of `SEL`
- specify `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN`
- if you plan to use `count(distinct(colC))` give it an alias, like `no_colC`

Also, what is the "L" value you reference in `SUM(L)`?  The query won't work as-is unless you include that field in your sub-select.

Comment: In addition to your suggestions: `distinct` is not a function. `distinct   a` is exactly the same thing as `distinct   (a)`

Comment: Yep, I agree...it's clearer without the `()`.  I updated my answer, thanks.